# shorten the namespace in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to shorten my namespace from say
**sandbox.auto.tools** to **sandbox.tools**. How do I achieve that (auto is redundant)? I looked through other messages but didn't really find something similar to what I am looking for. Below is my  directory structure.

```
sandbox\auto\tools\foo.py (contains a function display() as described below)
    def display():
        print "hello"

sandbox\test\bar.py 
    import sandbox.auto.tools as sandbox.tools (Error)
```

I know I can do the following.

```
  sandboox\test\bar.py 
    from sandbox.auto.tools import foo as tools
    tools.display()
```

Any suggestions/pointers ?

Comment: `import sandbox.auto as sandbox`?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't solve the problem. I need to then define the following statement - "from sandbox.tools import foo" and it gives me a error saying - no modules named tools.

Answer (score 3):

Allowing the exact syntax you specify (using `sandbox.tools` instead of `sandbox_tools`) will require altering the module, either before or after importing it.

The cheap way:

```
import sandbox.auto.tools
sandbox.tools = sandbox.auto.tools
```

The permanent way (requires ability to modify the module source):

Create or alter `sandbox/__init__.py` in the source to say:

```
import auto.tools as tools
__all__ = ['tools', ...]
```

Comment: display function is defined is foo.py. The above code is still not working for me. I am getting the error "ImportError: No module named tools"

Comment: Your `auto` and `tools` submodules may also need an `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want `sandbox.tools` to be available, add this to `sandbox/__init__.py`:

```
from .auto import tools
```

This adds `tools` to the namespace of the `sandbox` package and you will be able to do this:

```
from sandbox import tools
tools.dispaly()
```

Or, what you asked for, which is this:

```
import sandbox
sandbox.tools.display()
```

Comment: I am getting an ImportError. No module named tools

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution with your suggestions/help. However, I am still not satisfied with it.

sandbox/**init**.py

```
import auto.tools as tools
__all__ = ['tools']

import sandbox.auto.tools.foo
sandbox.tools.foo = sandbox.auto.tools.foo
```

sandbox/test/bar.py - this seems to work

```
import sandbox
print dir(sandbox)
foo = sandbox.tools.foo
foo.display()
```

However - I cannot say something like this anymore

```
from sandbox.tools import foo
or
from sandbox.tools import foo as tools2
```

It looks like I am able to get handle to references but I still don't fully understand the concept of namespaces in python.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleague pointed out that we could add the following line to sandbox/**init**.py and it should resolve this specific issue.

**path**.append('sandbox/auto')

Comment: For clarity: this refers to [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path), so you will have to import `sys` as well.